# Java SimpleDateFormat not working ok

Tags: java, android, date, timezone, simpledateformat

I have a weird problem with the SimpleDateFormat, the problem is that the date formatter is not parsing the date into my TimeZone, even when TimeZone.getDefault() gives me the right TimeZone.

If that is not enough, I run the following and I got the following results (in comment) :

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm a");

Date now = new Date();          
System.out.println(now);                            //   Wed Jul 03 18:58:37 CDT 2013
System.out.println(df.format(now));                 //   07/03/13 18:58 PM   (ok)
System.out.println(df.parse("07/03/13 18:58 PM"));  //   Wed Jul 03 00:58:00 CDT 2013 (not ok)
System.out.println(df.parse(df.format(now)));       //   Wed Jul 03 00:58:00 CDT 2013
```

How is that possible?? I'm not even sure what is the df.parse method doing, because the resulting hour never passes 1 AM, I mean, that was at 18:58, but now that my time is 7:32, I still get 00:32 instead of 1:32.

Am I missing something? The string dates are obtained from Server and their format cannot be altered because they are used in other already productive services.

This happens in an Android phone, the time is set ok in the Phone.

Comment: Ummm... those are not results, those are comments!!  Seriously.  What do you get if you run System.out.println(df.format(df.parse("07/03/13 18:34 PM")))?

Comment: Do you understand that you get a `Date` when using `SimpleDateFormat#parse` and a `Date` object doesn't have a pattern by itself, right?

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike it was to save space in the question, those are the prints, I will edit my question to include the sysouts...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza that is the default description for a Date Object "toString()". The resulting date millis are also different.

Comment: I tried your code (added sysos) and it worked fine.

Comment: Looks like you're not executing the code you think you're running.

Comment: This is what i get `Thu Jul 04 02:36:43 CEST 2013` `07/04/13 02:36 AM` `Wed Jul 03 18:34:00 CEST 2013` `Thu Jul 04 02:36:00 CEST 2013`.

Comment: I wonder if Android is getting confused because you have 24 hours and a AM/PM marker. Maybe try parsing the date with `"MM/dd/yy HH:mm"`

Comment: @samlewis yes it was the AM/PM marker, wasn't android, it was an error I had in the format string.

Comment: @Junaid given my answer, it happens that worked well for you because you are awake very early in the morning! (before 12 pm), go to sleep thanks! :)

Comment: @htafoya - hahaha. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I got it, the "not past 1 AM was the key"

the problem is that the parse text **"H"** is used in hours 0-23, for am-pm you should use **"h"** or **"K"**

The final format string must be:

```
"MM/dd/yy hh:mm a"
```

I think Java should send an error or warning trying to parse a past >12 hour instead of just replacing it by "00".

Comment: For the string you're parsing, H is fine.  It's odd, but fine.  Using your format string and your date string it parses properly for me.  If I use hh instead of HH it adds 12 hours to the time and says 07/04/13 06:34 AM
Thu Jul 04 06:34:00 PDT 2013

Comment: What I do not understand is why was `07/03/13 18:34 PM` being parsed to `Wed Jul 03 00:58:00 CDT 2013`. Even if we consider `H` to be the problem why were 24 minutes added.

Comment: Are you sure that's the format string you were using?  If you change it back to "MM/dd/yy HH:mm a" do you still get the bad date?  You should use whichever is appropriate for your data.  I'm just curious why it was happening as well.

Comment: @Junaid haha that was my error, I tested before but after I wrote the question I forgot to update that number.